# How to clone a github repo and add my fixes

Tags: git, github

I was wondering which would be the recommended way to do this, I will give the actual case.
I have corrected some scripts in an official repo of software, but the PRs take too long to merge to the master branch. I have my personal clone of that repo in gitHub.
Every time I am deploying this software I have to options by now:

1. git clone from the original repo and then manual copy/replace the fixed file, which does not scale and I not very user-friendly.
2. git clone from my repo, which works fine right away, but I am losing other fixes from the community/owner at the original repo, and on the other hand, users install software from me and not the real owner. This is not desirable too.

Any idea of how I could do this? clone the original and with one other line get my git fixed files and overwrite the original broken ones?

I imagine that this is not new, but I couldn't find the answer yet.

Thanks

Comment: How about cloning the original repo and apply your patch to it?

Comment: yes but how, can be done with git itself? I don't want to have an extra server to host the fixed files since I already have them on my repo

Answer (score 0):

Adrian,

Here is how it works:

You usually fork the latest version of a repo that you'd like to contribute to. You make your changes to the forked version and then submit a pull request to the maintainer of the original repo for review. If they like the changes, they implement them in their work.

Comment: This doesn't adress the mentioned problem that PRs (Pull Requests) take too long to me processed by the original authors.

Comment: Hi Nathan, yes, but the issue that I have is that the PR is taking too long to get approved and merged with the original repo. Is there a way to select specific files to download from a repo? in that way, I could clone the original and overwrite only with the fixed files from my repo.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you clone a remote repository (your clone on Github), it is automatically registered as "origin" remote repository. However, you can use `git remote add ...` to add another remote repository like e.g. the original as upstream.

For general maintenance, you rebase your local on the original remote branch, which also ensures that your fixes can still be applied. Then, you test and publish (use `--force-with-lease`) those changes to your cloned repository on Github. You can also selectively cherry-pick changes from the original repository to import bugfixes selectively.

For deployments, you then use your repository as source as before.